# Basic Math in Objective C on iPhone / iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, division, rounding

For some reasons I need the Integer and the Fraction part of a Double Value as two separate integers.

For Example : the Value 12.34 splitted into the Integers 12 and 34.

According to my basic knowledge of math this could easily be done via this expression that I'm using right now:

```
double aValue = 2.4f;
int aInt = (int)aValue;    
int aFract = (int)((aValue - aInt) * 100.0f );
```

It works so far but it has weird output behaviors.

For example passing 2.30000 results in '2' and '29' instead of '2' and '30'.

If I declare aInt and aFract as Double, the processing results correctly in '2.0000' and '30.0000' but converting '30.0000' into a integer results "interestingly" in '29' again.

Comment: [What you should know about floating point.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)  This question is also a duplicate hundreds of times over.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're running into inaccuracies with the representation of the number. Add 0.125 or so before truncating.

Comment: Thank You Ignacio. This approach works so far but I'm still not happy with it since I do not understand why 0.30 * 100.0 would lead to inaccuracies. Some rounding errors at numbers like 13.6546846516513512651 I would expect anyway. But not at a multiplication of "100" and "0.3".

Comment: @Tom, why not?  Those are base 10 numbers, and the computer works in base 2.

Comment: You are right Carl. Maybe I should use NSDecimal for such calculations. I'm aware that the computer works on base 2 but until now I was assuming that Float and Double would already handle the base 10/2 issue by default. Thank You Guys.

Comment: Yeah they handle it, but the unsolvable problems remain.  0.3 has no accurate representation in base 2 (it's 0b0.01001100110011…) and thus has an inherent error.  Multiply this by 100 (i. e. 0b1100100) and you get a binary 11101.111111111111…  Printing such a number can round it up, so the error does not show, while truncating it (which is done by using the `int` cast) will just keep the 11101 (== 29).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to convert some (small number less than 100 or so) and not inside a loop then converting to string would be more accurate, you will not fall into inaccuracies

it would be something like this

```
double aValue = 2.3;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", aValue];
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

now arr contains 2 and 3
please remember, a good programer is a lazy programer

Comment: It's all fun and games until it contains `2999999999999` instead.

Comment: Thank You, Omar. I was considering this solution already. It would work but would not fit in my case.In my opinion iOS has to do the math as expected. And 0.30 * 100.0 equals 30.0 and nothing else.

Comment: But 0.30 [can't be represented exactly as a binary number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.3+in+binary).  How do you propose the computer store that number?